# ruby on rails update page with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, model-view-controller, dynamic

I am using below button_to tag inside view file (index.html.erb)

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="20"><%=@write_date%></textarea>

 <%= button_to t(:get_date_write_new),channel_get_dates_path(@channel, :write => 1) %>
```

when i click the button it will get date from device and prints it on screen.

my question is that how do i make call to function "channel_get_dates_path(@channel, :write => 1)" continuously, and display the date in textarea without refreshing the page. by pressing the button only once?

my controller file:

```
class GetDatesController < ApplicationController
  include DateUtilities

  before_filter :require_user, :set_channels_menu
  def index
    @channel      = current_user.channels.find(params[:channel_id])
    @write_date = @channel.get_dates.write_dates.first
  end

  def create
    @channel = current_user.channels.find(params[:channel_id])
    @get_date = @channel.get_dates.write_dates.first

    if (@get_date.nil?)
      @get_date = GetDate.new
      @get_date.channel_id = @channel.id
      @get_date.user_id = current_user.id
      @get_date.write_flag = params[:write]
    end

    @get_date.get_date = generate_get_date
    @get_date.save

    redirect_to channel_get_dates_path(@channel)
  end 
end
```

and i have date generation file(myapp/lib) as:

```
module DateUtilities

  def generate_get_date

    require 'rubygems'

    require 'socket'

    hostname  =  '127.0.0.1'

    port      =   2000
    streamSock = TCPSocket.new( hostname, port )
    streamSock.write "ON"
    while line = streamSock.gets
        k = line
    end
    k
  end
end
```

Comment: you need to use AJAX for that case then

Comment: Why do you need display date if user won't edit it. Probably its easily create date within contorller action?

Comment: @deepak, while editing the formatting in your question I noticed that you were using tabs for indentation. The standard ruby formatting is to use 2 spaces for each indentation: you can change this in your IDE's settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the page without refreshing it, you need AJAX.

This can be done quite easily in rails by passing a `:remote => true` attribute in a form :

```
<%= form_tag(myupdate_path, :remote => true) do %>
  <%= form_tag(channel_get_dates_path(@channel, :write => 1), :remote => true) do %>
     <input type="submit" value="Get Today's Date">
     <input id="thedate" type="text" value="<%=@write_date%>">
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The remote option will call the `myupdate` method in your controller, and tell it to render a javascript view instead of a html view. Let's say you have in your controller :

```
def myupdate
  @thedate = params['wathever'] # get the params from the form
end
```

Then you can add your javascript method in myController/myupdate.js.erb ( instead of myupdate.html.erb). Assuming you're using jquery, this would be

```
$("#thedate").val("<%= @thedate %>") # dynamically update
```

By doing this you're able to get the params from the form, process it as you want with a controller, and tell javascript to update your page according to whathever you just put in your instance variable.

**Edit** : I used your form as the example. Hopefully the javascript is now more clear : the idea of the javascript view is to get the "thedate" html element in your page, and set its value according to the updated instance variable `@thedate`. This is where you tell javascript to dynamically update your page.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for precious suggestions now i am able to get the date in text field without refreshing the page.

Comment: i have one more question,
Whenever i press the button it will call the method in controller and display the date in text field without any page refresh,
Is it possible to make the date to display in text field continuously by pressing the button only once?

I tried calling the Controller method inside a loop and ended with Double render error. is it correct way or to make changes in view file?

Answer (score 0):

@Aurel,thanks for your suggestions. i followed your steps.

in my view file changed the code as:

```
  <%= form_tag(channel_get_dates_path(@channel, :write => 1), :remote => true) do %>
     <input type="submit" value="Get Today's Date">
     <input type="text" value="<%=@write_date%>">
  <% end %>
```

after this when i press the submit button the update method is called(and i can see that device is sending the date), but the date is not displaying in text field. when i refresh the page the last obtained date from device is displayed in text field.
Is it possible to display the date every time when press submit button?